# how to access files in phone or SD card memory

Tags: android, file, system

hello guys i need small help in understanding file system of android

Now in windows for example we create files using paths like `"c:/mytextfile.txt"` or `"c:/folder/mytextfile.txt"`.Now how can i access files and folders in android i mean whats the path like.

Does the phone support file browser instead of relying on third party apps??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android does not have a native file browser, but there are numerous third-party ones (Astro comes to mind). The filesystem of Android is that of Linux; the path separator is / and the FS grows from a single root called /. So, you have your app packages under /data/apps, and so forth. Unless the phone is jailbroken ("rooted"), you won't get to see the whole filesystem - permissions get in the way. This applies to all Android applications, they are sandboxed - that is, they don't get access the whole filesystem. There are API calls to get the path to the current application's sandbox directory.